# AngularJS FORMs: Fetch Items for second SELECT BOX based on previous input

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

PHP guy here, trying to build auto-update forms using AngularJS

My forms looks like this:

```
<div ng-app="myapp">
 <div ng-controller="ctrl">
  Select Road Name: <select ng-model="roadname" ng-options="x  for x in roadNames" name="forms_roadName"></select>
  Select Bus Stop Name: <select ng-model="busstopname" ng-options="x  for x in busStopNames"  name="forms_BusStopName"></select>
</div>
```

And relevant section of my javascript is:

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.roadNames = function_getRoadNames();
    if ($scope.roadname !== null) {  
     $scope.busstopname = function_getBusStopNames($scope.roadname);
    } else { $scope.busstopname = ["Select Roadname first"]; }
 });
```

I am expecting the Bus Stop names SELECT BOX to auto-update based on the selected Roadname. Its not happening. Chrome console does not throw any error, the "if" condition is never met and "else" block is always executed. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ng-change

```
 <select ng-change="updateRoad()" ng-model="roadname" ng-options="x  for x in roadNames" name="forms_roadName"></select>
```

In your controller add a method updateRoad()

```
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.roadNames = function_getRoadNames();
    if ($scope.roadname !== null) {  
     $scope.busstopname = function_getBusStopNames($scope.roadname);
    } else { $scope.busstopname = ["Select Roadname first"]; }

   $scope.updateRoad = function() {
        $scope.busstopname = function_getBusStopNames($scope.roadname);
   }
 });
```